# What happened to the groom at the Red Wedding?

Tags: game-of-thrones

What happened to the character that was dragged off by Walder's daughters? Maybe I missed it but can I assume he got killed like the others?

Comment: You mean the one that got married? That shows up later in the show?

Comment: @Radhil Ah okay. I'm only on s6

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edmure Tully** is the name of the groom that married Roslin Frey at the Red Wedding.

He was not killed, and not really because he was part of the family now.  Edmure was kept hostage at the Twins following the massacre, as he was heir to Riverrun, and keeping the Tully family and Riverrun in check once the Starks were removed was a high priority for all involved.  Edmure will show up later to have an effect on the plot.

Comment: "Edmure will show up later to have an effect on the plot." Too true - in the game of thrones, you are either saved until you're needed for the plot, or you die. Probably both, though. Mortality rate is pretty high for named characters.

Comment: @corsiKa: I prefer to think of it as, "If you (the reader/viewer) find yourself sympathizing, empathizing, or just generally liking a character, expect their lifespan to be no more than 1 book/season."

Comment: @tonysdg my fav character isnt dead yet ... long live Arya

Comment: Some say Gendry is still rowing towards an island.

Comment: Ned Stark, wearing a red shirt, showing everyone pictures of his kids while talking about how it is his last day before retirement.

Comment: @TLP, ouch - right in the feels!